# How do I not get duplicates in this list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to take two lists with different lengths, and trying to make a third list which contains the same numbers using list comprehension. I want to avoid duplicates.

I attempted to use list comprehension with an if test, as I will show in the code. I also attempted an and statement, but that does not work.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
c = [x for x in a if x in b]
```

This is the current solution I have, 'I also tried to alter the c list comprehension to:

```
c = [x for x in a if x in b and x not in c]
```

But this did not work. Is this not possible using list comprehension? I am aware that I can do this using sets quite easily. I am just practicing the use of list comprehension.

Comment: What should the answer be?

Comment: Just convert the two lists to sets and take union `list(set(a) | set(b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your reasons for using a list for c, you could consider using the built-in `set` structure to do intersection operations and which guarantees uniqueness of elements. For instance, `set(a)` will produce  a set containing the unique elements in `a`.

`c = [x for x in a if x in b]` does not work since the duplicate elements in `a` are still contained in `b` and therefore not excluded by your if statement. (`1` is duplicated in `a`, but both elements will be contained in `c` by your first definition, since `1` is in `b`).

EDIT: if you want to simply modify your list comprehension but continue using it, you could do something like: `c = [x for x in set(a) if x in b]`

Comment: you can convert a set to list by doing (e.g) d = list(c) (where c is the set of a and b) but the order would not be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new list of all elements that appear in either of the 2 original lists, you could use the `set` class to achieve that. Maybe like this:

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

>>> list(sorted(set(a) | set(b)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

What this does is building 2 sets from the lists, then finding the [union](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) of all the elements and then convert the result back to a list.

This approach will be faster than checking `elem for elem in a if elem in b` for large lists, because membership tests are `O(1)` for sets but up to `O(n)` for lists.

Answer (score 0):

I will present a slightly different solution: The idea would be to first count the frequency of numbers using `Counter` and then perform the list comprehension using the keys. Since `Counter` returns a dictionary, you will not have duplicate keys.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

f1 = Counter(a)
f2 = Counter(b)

c = [x for x in f1.keys() if x in f2.keys()]
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```